# logging | error() gets sent to FileHandler... but not other Logging Levels

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am able to store **error** logs to a file... but not **info()** or any other [Logging Levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels).

**What am I doing wrong?**

**How can I store any level of logs to FileHandler?**

---

`code.py`

```py
import sys
import logging

def setup_logging():
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    open('data_module.log', 'w').close()  # empty logs
    global fileHandler
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('data_module.log')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    logger.error('Started')  # info
    logger.info('information')  # info
```

`test.py`:

```py
import code as c

c.setup_logging()

with open('data_module.log', 'r') as fileHandler:
    logs = [l.rstrip() for l in fileHandler.readlines()]
open('data_module.log', 'w').close()  # empty logs

assert len(logs) == 2
```

Error:

```
AssertionError: assert 1 == 2
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I should add to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the level for the logger itself:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The default log level is WARN: when you write a DEBUG-level message, the logger does not handle it (ie send it to a handler). The handler you added is never invoked.

The handler can have its own level, but that is consulted only after the handler is invoked. If a logger sends a DEBUG message to a handler that is only interested in INFO+ messages, it does nothing.

Comment: I used your line right after `logger = `. Thank you :)